# XML post to web api maps to null

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

In webapiconfig I have

```
 config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Controller

```
 public class PersonController : ApiController
 {
    [HttpPost]
    public void Submit([FromBody]Person person)
    {
        // Do something with person
    }
}
```

Case 1 (Works, i.e. person object get the value from posted XML)
When I post XML like this

```
 <Person>
   <Name>Alex</Name>
   <Country>USA</Country>
 </Person>
```

Case 2 (Doesn't work, i.e. person object is null) When I post XML like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0 encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Person xmlns:xsd="http:www.w3.org/2001/XMLScheme"  
    xmlns:xsi="http:www.w3.org/2001/XMLScheme-instance">
  <Name>Alex</Name>
  <Country>USA</Country>
 </Person>
```

What should I do to make Case 2 person object get the XML posted values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide namespace as an attribute to node `Person`.

So use below class structure to get it to work with Case 2,

```
[XmlRoot("Person")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ok got it you forgot to add closing double quotes here => `version="1.0` it should be `version="1.0"` (mention that closing double quote)